# How to resize uitableview inside of container view in xcode using auto-layout or programatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uicontainerview

I have a uitableview inside of a container view that I want to fit perfectly inside of the uiviewcontroller that i have inside of my container view. I tried adding leading, trailing top and bottom constraints from the uitableview to the view, but doing this made the tableview disappear when running the app. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set  `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to  NO